# Amazon Scraping returns 503

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` and using UserAgent while making request. Amazon is blocking my calls though I did add a sleep method to avoid it. Is there anyway to deal with it? I know there's an API available but I doubt I would get what I am looking for.

What I want to get product details based on ASIN and it returns all price offers by different sellers using **Amazon Prime** shipping option, the example URL given [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B009OZUPUC/sr=/qid=/ref=olp_prime_new?ie=UTF8&colid=&coliid=&condition=new&me=&qid=&seller=&shipPromoFilter=1&sort=sip&sr).

Comment: amazon has an api I believe. .. just sign up for a developer account and use the channels they approve of for this ...

Comment: Yeah but I need Seller Details provide Prime Shipping, so far I could not find option

Comment: ok yeah I dunno enough about their api to help... but google wasnt super helpful with that ... good luck

Comment: @Volatil3 did you find a way on handling this?

Comment: @CamiloAguilar I don't remember at the moment how did I sort this out. Are you having similar issue?

Comment: @Volatil3 yes. I had some ideas in my mind. I have something similar but with Java.

Comment: If amazon detect a bot (which is still possoble if you incude short sleeps), they will block you. So try using a VPN to mask you location. Using variable parameter will help avoid detection. Top things to change in between a long running scraper are IP and User Agent

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to deal with it?

Yes... you comply with their acceptable use policy.

If it's not available from an API, you're not authorized to scrape it.

Even if you successfully scrape it, you're *still* not authorized to use it.

> This license does not include any resale or commercial use of any Amazon Service, or its contents; any collection and use of any product listings, descriptions, or prices; any derivative use of any Amazon Service or its contents; any downloading, copying, or other use of account information for the benefit of any third party; or any use of data mining, robots, or similar data gathering and extraction tools.
>
> https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ap_frn_condition_of_use?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508088

Comment: The problem with this is how you enroll in their developer program in order to use their `API`, they ask you to setup a website with products you sell and also promote amazon website, they also ask you to enroll as a seller...is kind of non-sense and overkill IMHO

Comment: web scraping is an important part of not having a few players dominate the web. it's also absurd to think amazon doesn't do large amounts of web scraping for its own price comparisons and analytics.

Comment: waw, that sounded patronizing, how about a technical answer rather than a moralizing one ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are scraping amazon search results page,e.g. [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=iphone%2011) , then amazon only requires you have a user-agent set, and don't scrape too aggressively (i.e. it will block/rate limit you if you send too many requests from one IP address)

If you are scraping a product page, e.g. [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B082P6M3HC/), the rate limits are much stricter per IP.

If your use case is not very intense the amazon seller api is your best bet, and only requires a professional selling account to use, see https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/ typically has rate limits of 1-10 per second for data like prices, barcodes etc

Answer (score 1):

amazon has bots and all to prevent the web scrappers and scrapping automation.
just search for your user agent and provide it as a dictionary when using the get method
`url= "<link>" header = { "User-Agent": "<search result of user agent>", } page=requests.get(url,headers=header)`

Comment: They're still able to block IP addresses, though, regardless of http headers